# Laravel - Remove elements having NULL value from multidimentional array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using `Laravel 5.3`.

I have a `multidimensional array` like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 37141
    [last_done_on] => []
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => NULL /* This must be removed */
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37142
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array()
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37143
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37144
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37145
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                        )
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37157
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37158
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37159
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => NULL  /* This must be removed */
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And I want to `remove` the `elements` that are `NULL`. So the result should be like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 37141
    [last_done_on] => []
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37142
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array()
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37143
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37144
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37145
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 37157
                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37158
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array()
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37159
                                    [last_done_on] => Array()
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How to do this?

Comment: This is the thing that annoys me about frameworks, it causes people to overlook the functionality that the underlying programming language provides.  You don't need any fancy "web artisan" nonsense, just PHP's array_filter() function and a working knowledge of recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the `null` values but not the empty arrays you could do something like:

```
function array_remove_null($item)
{
    if (!is_array($item)) {
        return $item;
    }

   return collect($item)
        ->reject(function ($item) {
            return is_null($item);
        })
        ->flatMap(function ($item, $key) {

            return is_numeric($key)
                ? [array_remove_null($item)]
                : [$key => array_remove_null($item)];
        })
        ->toArray();
}

$newArray = array_remove_null($array);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems working!! but I also want to reorder the keys. For example by removing element that is having NULL value from 0th position, the next element should become 0th.

Comment: @Dev I've updated my answer to include a way to reset numeric keys.

Answer (score 11):

In collection, use filter

```
some_collection->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return  $value != null;
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but it does not answering the question about multidimensional array. For flat array it is fine.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options to use:

```
$yourArr = array_map('array_filter', $yourArr);
```

or

```
$yourArr = array_filter( $yourArr);
```

all keys with a null value will be eliminated

Comment: @Dev Just this line should do 
$yourArr= array_filter( $yourArr);
See example #2 here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

In your case the array you want to clear up is having the key 'children', so the exact line would be 

$arr = array_filter($arr['children']);

Comment: @GSBajaj might be you're not getting my question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   function array_filter_recursive($input) 
   { 
      foreach ($input as &$value) 
      { 
           if (is_array($value)) 
           { 
               $value = array_filter_recursive($value); 
           } 
      }     
      return array_filter($input, function($var){return !is_null($var);} ); 
   }
```

Comment: It removes all the elements that are empty. I don't want to remove the keys ```children``` or ```last_done_on``` even if they are empty. Also it disturbs the keys of the array.

Comment: Edited to remove only null values